# Help with resizing hard drive after failed Boot Camp

Tags: imac, bootcamp, partition

The other day I tried to install Windows 8.1 on my iMac (Mid-2011, 21.5 inch) running OS X Yosemite 10.10.1. The process froze halfway through, resulting in me losing 100 GB (which was suppose to be allocated for Windows) on my main Hard drive.

After running `diskutil list`, my output is…

```
    /dev/disk0
    #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
    0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
    1:                  Apple_HFS Mac HD                  399.2 GB   disk0s1
```

As you can see, I have `FDisk_partition_scheme` which is 500.1 GB and my main `Apple_HFS` called, Mac HD which has all my files and folders, that is 399.2 GB. I wish to make my Mac HD ~500 GB so I can recover that 100 GB that has disappeared.

I also believe that I'm missing a Recovery HD. When I boot with `Command` + `R`, I am shown a spinning globe which downloads some sort of outdated recovery (because it shows the old UI). Every time I boot my iMac, I booted into Windows side (somehow?) with the message of something similar "No disk found" etc.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

---

Output for `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0`:

```
Disk: /dev/disk0        geometry: 60801/255/63 [976773168 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: AF   25 127  15 - 1023 254  63 [    409640 -  779781456] HFS+        
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

---

Output for `sudo gdisk /dev/disk0`:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.10

Warning: Devices opened with shared lock will not have their
partition table automatically reloaded!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid MBR and GPT. Which do you want to use?
 1 - MBR
 2 - GPT
 3 - Create blank GPT

Your answer:

Your answer: 2
Using GPT and creating fresh protective MBR.

Command (? for help):
```

---

Output for `sudo gpt -r -vv show disk0`:

```
gpt show: disk0: mediasize=500107862016; sectorsize=512; blocks=976773168
gpt show: disk0: MBR at sector 0
gpt show: disk0: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: disk0: Sec GPT at sector 976773167
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         MBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  779781456      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  780191096    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  781460632        872         
  781461504  195311616      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  976773120         15         
  976773135         32         Sec GPT table
  976773167          1         Sec GPT header
```

---

Output for `sudo gpt show /dev/disk0`:

```
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         MBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  779781456      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  780191096    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  781460632        872         
  781461504  195311616      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  976773120         15         
  976773135         32         Sec GPT table
  976773167          1         Sec GPT header
```

Comment: You are definitely missing the EFI Partition (around 200 MB) and the Apple_Boot Partition (around 120 MB). Very strange.

Comment: please add the output from the command `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0` to the question - depending on the partition layout, there may not be enough space for a GPT

Comment: start 409640, I think you accident deleted the EFI partition(200M), and the partition scheme change to MBR

Comment: run `sudo gpt show /dev/disk1` and show the result

Comment: sorry, `sudo gpt show /dev/disk0`

Comment: @Noah I've check it, the partition information for your disk almost fine, except the first sector. from my side of view, it shows `start       size  index  contents`
          `0          1         PMBR`

Comment: @klanomath I understand. What do you think my best option is? If I end up using Recovery Mode, can I install OS X from USB/Harddrive? I can't really re-download ~3GB+. I also have a backup of my Home folder, so I can easily re-transfer all my settings, files and folders. All I want is, to have my HDD restored back with that 100 GB that I lost from re-partioning.

Comment: @Noah First make a new full time machine backup. Give me a comment if you are finished

Comment: @Noah I suggest you backup whole OS X system first via time machine. after that you can try GPT fdisk[http://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/], if failed, you can make a internet recovery and restore from your time machine.

Comment: @nelson, can you explain to me what GPT fdisk does? How do I use it?

Comment: @Noah Sorry I don't known more detail about it.

Comment: @klanomath thanks a **ton** for your help. I restored from a backup yesterday and I now have a normal 500.11 GB Macintosh HD. The only thing I don't have is a Recovery HD. I found out from experience that I don't need one. If I have my backup disk plugged in it'll go a recovery mode stored on there (?)